# Discrepancy in size of long int

Tags: c

I'm getting a size discepancy while using `long int` in C. The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(long int));
}
```

gives 8 as output, so 64 bits are used to represent `long int`, right? But:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    long int a;
    a = 1;
    a = a << 32;
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

gives 0 (shifting by 31 gives -2147483648, which is -2**31). So, it seems that only 4 bytes are being used. What does this mean? I'm using gcc 4.4.5 with no flags

Comment: Do you need a modifier on the "%d" format specifier?  Not sure. Try "%ld" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're printing it as a normal integer: `printf("%d")`. Try printing it as a long integer: `printf("%ld ...")`.